# Proper MySQL way to add a column from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sqlperformance

I have a large table (~10 million records) that contains several keys into other, smaller tables.  The keys are unique in each of the smaller tables but not in the large one.  I would like to add a column to the large table from one of the smaller tables based on the keys matching, but I'm not sure of the "right" way to do it.  I have a solution that works, but it takes a fair amount of time (thought that may be unavoidable) and just generally doesn't feel like it's the optimal way to do it.  Here's what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE new_big_table LIKE big_table;
ALTER TABLE new_big_table ADD(new_column TINYINT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO new_big_table SELECT big_table.*, smaller_table.my_column
  FROM big_table JOIN smaller_table ON big_table.key1 = smaller_table.key1
  AND big_table.key2 = smaller_table.key2;
```

This gets the job done, but it really smells like I'm doing it all wrong.  It seems like at minimum I shouldn't need to create a duplicate of the table to get this done.  Is there some more direct (and more efficient?) way of doing this?

It might be worth mentioning that this is for a personal, hobby project at home, so I am free to hog all the resources of the machine (since I'm the only one using it).  As such, if there are any straightforward performance tuning tips for doing things like this, I'd appreciate them (I'm experimenting with this on an Amazon EC2 instance since it should be a lot faster and have more memory than my personal desktop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to add the column in-place?

```
alter table big_table add new_column tinyint;

update  big_table bt
join    smaller_table st
on      bt.key1 = st.key1
        and bt.key2 = st.key2
set     bt.new_column = st.my_column;

alter table big_table modify new_column tinyint not null;
```

Comment: No I haven't tried that; I'm not familiar with the update syntax when there is a select involved.  I felt like something like what you suggested probably existed though, so assuming that does what I think it does that might be exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: @Michael McGowan: Just remembered you can actually `join` in MySQL update statements... answer improved :)

Comment: That seemed to produce the same result as mine, and it was cleaner in not needing to create a new table.  Oddly enough though, it took slightly longer.  Your `update` was slightly faster than my `insert`, but adding the the blank column `big_table` took a fair amount of time.  Is that an indicator that I'm doing something else poorly?

Comment: @Michael McGowan: Adding a column might require a table reorg that's more expensive than copying the entire table.  Sounds normal to me, I wouldn't take it as an indicator of something being done poorly.

Comment: Alter statements on large tables are very expensive queries. An alter statement makes a copy of the table, performs the alteration, deletes the original and renames the temporary table to replace the original. As you can imagine that a lot of disk IO when you get into millions of rows.